# Ubuntu livecd hangs - unable to access my laptop

Tags: laptop, live-cd

My Acer Aspire Laptop is unbootable.

I'm trying to reinstall Ubuntu 10.04.1. Boot options accessible OK via F2.

In fact, it still leads me into the olg grub2 menu, but I can't use any of the options because of corrupted installations on the various partitions (hence my wish to reinstall). Any type of LiveCD hangs in the middle of the installation.

With ubuntu-10.04.1-desktop-i385.iso (MD5Sum checked), the installation seems to hang at "Running /script/casper-premount" (when run in non-quite mode), (and nothing seems to happen from there).

I tried various other installations (via UNetBootin eg RescueCD on USB stick etc)... The laptop seems to access both USB and CDROM ok...

My laptop has become totally unusable? What can I do? Is the 'c' option at the old GRUB2 menu of any use?

Any help would be much appreciated - I'm rather desperate to get my laptop working again!

Answer (score 2):

Using SystemRescueCD (on a CD, rather than USB), reformatting the partition and using Ubuntu LiveCD again worked OK.